# MATLAB's $\tt cpsd$ and $\tt pwelch$ - different results for cross spectral power density

Tags: power-spectral-density, fourier

I am wondering why the following code does not yield the same results for `Sxy1` and `Sxy2`, where `Sxy1` is calculated using the MATLAB's `pwelch` function, and `Sxy2` is calculated using `cpsd` function.

```
fs = 1000;
t = 0:1/fs:5-1/fs;
win=hann(500);
overlap=300;
nfft=500;
fs=1000;   

x = cos(2*pi*100*t)+randn(size(t));
y=sin(2*pi*160*t)+cos(2*pi*150*t)+randn(size(t));

[Sxx,f] = pwelch(x,win,overlap,nfft,fs);
[Syy,f] = pwelch(y,win,overlap,nfft,fs);

Sxy1=sqrt(Sxx.*Syy); %******

[Sxy2,f] = cpsd(x,y,win,overlap,nfft,fs);

Sxy2=abs(Sxy2); %******
```

Comment: Hint: because the cross power spectral density is NOT equal to $\sqrt{S_{xx} \cdot S_{yy}}$ ...

Comment: Thanks! This is what I suspected. Do you know the equation for cross power spectral density in terms of power spectra?

I believe, for amplitude spectra: 

Sxy = (1/L) .\times (X(ejw) .\times conj(Y(ejw)) is correct?

Where X(ejw) and Y(ejw) are the complex spectra of the x and y signals.

Comment: Did you compare the Sxy above to the output of cpsd? The Sxy you specify in the above comment is an estimate of the cross power spectral density (depending on how the DFT is scaled an additional scaling factor might be required). To get the same result as cpsd make sure you use the same window, overlap, number of averages etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no function that I am aware of that outputs complex amplitude spectra  using Welch's method (only power spectra). I am currently in the process of coding one that does, but it would be easier if I had an equation for CPSD in terms of (real valued) power spectra.

Comment: Isn’t that exactly what cpsd does? (You should remove the abs in your last line of example code above to get the complex spectrum.) See “edit cpsd.m” to see how cross power spectral density calculation, using Welch’s method, is implemented in Matlab.

Comment: Hmm well, the cpsd function outputs cross spectral POWER density using Welch's method, which is fine, but, as mentioned, there is no function that outputs AMPLITUDE spectra using Welch's method. (excuse caps)

And, for various reasons that I haven't mentioned, I wish to calculate the CPSD using the power spectra calculated using the pwelch function. 

Hence why I'd like to know the equation for Sxy in terms of Sxx and Syy...

Comment: This might be a matter of semantics but as the cross power spectral density (cpsd) is inherently a complex quantity it is not possible to calculate it from the power spectral density (which is a real quantity). The cpsd contains information describing the phase between two signals. This information is not available in the power spectral density; hence it cannot be used to calculate the cpsd.

Comment: Welch’s method uses overlapped, averaged FFT’s and their complex conjugates to estimate the PSD. You cannot use this method to directly calculate an amplitude spectrum as, in general, you cannot average the complex FFT (converges to zero if signals are noisy). You can calculate an amplitude spectrum from a PSD estimated using Welch’s method (AS = sqrt(2*PSD*df)) but, as the PSD, this will not contain any phase information and hence cannot be used to calculate the cpsd.

Comment: Thanks for your input, much appreciated! Yes that makes a lot of sense - I have since abandoned trying to calculate CPSD from any Welch inspired function, and instead have coded my own Welch algorithm that allows me to apply processes to the FFTs before the CPSD is calculated using the Sxy = (1/L) .\times (X(ejw) .\times conj(Y(ejw))  relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I have not worked out how to calculate CPSD from power spectra, I have confirmed the following two methods are equivalent (using amplitude spectra, rather than power spectra or cross-correlation):

```
Fs = 1000;
t = 0:1/Fs:1-1/Fs;
x = cos(2*pi*100*t) + randn(size(t));
y=sin(2*pi*160*t)+cos(2*pi*150*t)+randn(size(t));
N = length(x);
nfft=500;
lfft=2*nfft;
overlap=0;
win=rectwin(N);

xdft1 = fft(x,2*nfft);  <outputs two-sided complex amplitude spectra
ydft1 = fft(y,2*nfft);
Sxy1a=xdft1.*conj(ydft1);   
Sxy1b=Sxy1a./N^2;
Sxy1c=Sxy1b(1:lfft/2+1);
Sxy1c(2:end-1)=2*Sxy1c(2:end-1);
Sxy1=abs(Sxy1c)';

%CPSD Method 2
Sxy2a=cpsd(x,y,win,overlap,2*nfft,Fs);   < uses the cpsd function with Welch’s overlapped method
Sxy2=abs(Sxy2a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the last piece of code and it works. I'll just add my piece of code to show how it works with any Fs and fft points but only 50% overlap.

```
resultx = EEG.data(5,1:16384);
resulty = EEG.data(3,1:16384);
Fs = 250;
Navg = 127;
nfft = 256;
samplesread = nfft-1;
window = hamming(nfft);
xmulconjyfft = zeros(nfft/2+1,Navg);
for i=1:Navg % number of iterations, that depends on fft points and the overlap, in my case with fftpoints=256, 50% overlap and inputlength=2^14, the number of iterations is 127 
endpoint=startingpoint+samplesread; %read 255 data points every time
x1=resultx(startingpoint:endpoint)'.*window;
y1=resulty(startingpoint:endpoint)'.*window;
xdft1 = fft(x1,nfft);  
ydft1 = fft(y1,nfft);
startingpoint=startingpoint+(samplesread+1)/2;
Sxy1a=ydft1.*conj(xdft1);   
Sxy1b=Sxy1a./N^2;
Sxy1c=Sxy1b(1:nfft/2+1);
Sxy1c(2:end-1)=2*Sxy1c(2:end-1);
Sxy1c = Sxy1c';
xmulconjyfft(:,i)=Sxy1c;
%Sxy1=abs(Sxy1c);
end

avgxyfft = mean(xmulconjyfft,2); %average the spectrums 
avgxyfft= avgxyfft*((length(resultx).^2)/(nfft*Fs)); % normalization factor

Sxy2a=cpsd(resultx,resulty,window,[],nfft,Fs);
```

From code above Sxy2a and avgxyfft result in two identical vectors with complex values.